# ExpandableListView with NumberPicker child will not expand

Tags: android, expandablelistview, numberpicker

I'm new to android development, and I have and expandable list view that has a number picker as the child. When I click on the group, the group will not expand. Here is what I have currently:

main layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/leadTrackerExpand"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/tracklist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ExpandableListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

group layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/ltDetails"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ltGroupHeader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
   />

</LinearLayout>
```

child layout

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ltDetails"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/pickNum"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Adapter

```
public class LeadTrackerAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {


    private Activity context;
    private String[] ltHeader;

    public LeadTrackerAdapter(Activity context, String[] ltHeader){
        this.context = context;
        this.ltHeader = ltHeader;
    }
    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return ltHeader.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return ltHeader[groupPosition];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View header = convertView;
        String trackHeaderName = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);

        if (header == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lt_group,
                    null);
            TextView item = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.ltGroupHeader);
           // item.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            item.setText(trackHeaderName);
            }


        return header;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;

         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                 .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lt_details,
                 null);

         NumberPicker numPicker = (NumberPicker)row.findViewById(R.id.pickNum);
         numPicker.setMaxValue(100);
         numPicker.setMinValue(0);
         numPicker.setValue(0);

        return row;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

Activity class

```
public class LeadTrackerActivity extends ExpandableListActivity {

    String[] groupList;
    ExpandableListView ltList;
    LeadTrackerAdapter ltAdapter;


     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            ltList = getExpandableListView();
            ltList.setGroupIndicator(null);
            ltList.setClickable(true);

            populateGroupList();

            ltAdapter = new LeadTrackerAdapter(LeadTrackerActivity.this, groupList);
            setListAdapter(ltAdapter);

            ltList.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener(){

                @Override
                public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                        int groupPosition, long id) {

                    (parent.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)));
                    if (parent.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) {
                        parent.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
                    } else {
                       parent.expandGroup(groupPosition);
                    }

                    return true;
                }

            });
     }


    private void populateGroupList() {
        groupList  = new String[]{"Follow-up Calls", "Team Building Leads", "Recruit Leads",
                "Interviews", "Sells"};

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer after viewing other posts that where working with ExpandableListView and playing around with a few things. In my case. I needed to change the children count to 1 which is the number of numberpickers I wanted to be displayed. like below

```
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 1;
}
```